# Flink StreamingFileSink RowFormatBuilder withBucketAssigner returns Any?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Why does this configuration result in Any type? I can't call .build()! My flink version is 1.10.0 and scala version is 2.11
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahvdj.png)

```scala
    val sink = StreamingFileSink
      .forRowFormat(new Path("s3a://123"), csvEncoder)
      .withRollingPolicy(
        DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
          .withRolloverInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(5))
          .withInactivityInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(5))
          .withMaxPartSize(128 * 1024 * 1024)
          .build()
      )
      .withBucketAssigner(
        new BucketAssigner[UserEvent, String] {
          override def getBucketId(element: UserEvent, context: BucketAssigner.Context): String = element.getType.name
          override def getSerializer: SimpleVersionedSerializer[String] = new SimpleVersionedStringSerializer
        }
      ) // this returns Any!!!
      .build() // can't call .build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the type inference of Scala in combination with the self-type idiom used by the `StreamingFileSink` builders.

As a quick fix you could insert a cast:

```
val sink = StreamingFileSink
  .forRowFormat(new Path("s3a://123"), csvEncoder)
  .withRollingPolicy(
    DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
      .withRolloverInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(5))
      .withInactivityInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(5))
      .withMaxPartSize(128 * 1024 * 1024)
      .build()
  )
  .withBucketAssigner(
    new BucketAssigner[UserEvent, String] {
      override def getBucketId(element: UserEvent, context: BucketAssigner.Context): String = element.getType.name
      override def getSerializer: SimpleVersionedSerializer[String] = new SimpleVersionedStringSerializer
    }
  ).asInstanceOf[StreamingFileSink.RowFormatBuilder[UserEvent, String, _]]
  .build()
```

The proper fix requires changes to Flink. You can track [FLINK-16684](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16684) to get notified when the problem is properly fixed.

#### Update

The problem has been fixed with Flink 1.10.1 and 1.11.0.

Comment: Just a quick update @Patrick, the problem has been fixed in 1.10.1 and 1.11.0.